# Including the same file twice with the same function name

Tags: php, function

Here is a situation.

I want to duplicate an API twice on my server but with different databases. What I want to do is to use some function of these API's. In PHP I have a situation where I am implmenting a loop of all these API locations.

```
forach($apis as $api){
 include ($api->apiFiles);
 useAPIfunction();
}
```

the problem is The API have the same functions and classes, the loop runs one time but for the second time the PHP Fatal error cannot redeclare function" occurs.

Now I don't want to change the API like changing function names etc, I have to do all from my script. Is there a situation to unregister the API file after the first iteration completed because it is the only way to include the new API.

Thanks in Advance for Help.

Comment: is the only difference the database used?

Comment: yes it is the only difference

Comment: then pass that as an argument nothing needs to be duplicated

Comment: Put the APIs in a class, having them refer to a member variable for the database.  Set that member variable to the database in the class constructor.

Comment: Try to find the database connect class

Comment: I have done a trick. I included the API files on the first iteration and then for the second I connected to the second database. Now the API will be connected once using the first API files but the Database is changing on every new iteration.
    
    forach($apis as $api){
     if($count = 0){
      include ($api->apiFiles);
     }else{
      mysql_connect($api->host,$api->username,$api->password);
      mysql_select_db($api->db);
     }
     useAPIfunction();
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a trick. I included the API files on the first iteration and then for other iteration add a script to connected to the second database and vice verse. Now the API will be connected once using the first API files but the Database is changing on new iteration. Also I did not found a way to get The Database Info so I retrieved it from the API config file.

```
forach($apis as $api){
 if($count = 0){
  include ($api->apiFiles);
 }else{
  $theData = file_get_contents($api->path'\includes\config.php', NULL, NULL, 10, 600);
  $theData = str_replace('<?php','',$theData);
  $theData = explode("'",$theData);
  $apiHost = $theData[19];
  $apiDB = $theData[7];
  $apiDbUser = $theData[11];
  $apiDBPass = $theData[15];

  mysql_connect($apiHost,$apiUser,$apiPass);
  mysql_select_db($apiDB);
 }
 useAPIfunction();
```

}

Comment: This solution seems to be very specific to your environment, since your API config files apparently have very consistent layouts that you're depending on. But the syntax of your file_get_contents call doesn't look valid to me.  There's something very wrong with the way your APIs are designed if you have to go through hoops like this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the same API multiple times, you just include it once (you can use the `include_once` command to avoid loading the same API multiple times). Ideally, the API should take parameters telling it what database to use. But if it uses global variables, you set the variables before calling the API functions. It's best for it to use parameters, because the second way means that you can only use one database at a time.